# Downloading a file over HTTP while it is being downloaded on the server

Tags: wget

I have a download going on on a internal network over HTTP (only available protocol) using `wget`. The content of interest is NOT reachable from the WWW. The file is being downloaded to a public http accessible directory on a server that IS reachable from the WWW. Is it possible to externally begin downloading this file while it is still being downloaded on the server? This really would speed up the distribution process.

```
Private Server -> Public Server - WWW -> Client Server
```

Comment: Ditch `wget` and configure a [Reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) server instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the tools being used at the far end to download the file.  if they are using wget with resume or another with the option to resume it may work depending on how smart the tool is.

other side is how long it takes for the pub server to recieve the file from you?  Can some one download it faster than you can upload it to the server? some of the download apps either are dumb or smart enough that the file size change will not be a problem how ever if a user finishes what you have available on the server they may not go looking for more of a file if it said it completed normally.

At the least a note stating file copy in process and finished size  should be included so users know if its done. a MD5 is also a good idea to allow verification after they finish downloading.

Comment: Anybody still using MD5? I'd go with something more modern like perhaps SHA384.

Comment: any thing is better than nothing. I have a shell app in winblows that adds a tab with several hashes md5 was the one I had used previously so I use that.  I doubt the win app has sha384. I have a function in nsis that does md5 duno if it has a sha384 either.